# local search paths and transactions in postgres

Tags: postgresql

How do `search_path`s work inside a transaction? Suppose, three different inserts statements are done altering `postgres`'s `search_path`, then, when a transaction is committed, shouldn't the table be affected which belongs to the latest search path? Consider the example:

```
create table mlwork.namedata(  | create table mmwork.namedata(  | create table mnwork.namedata(
 id integer primary key,       | id integer primary key,        | id integer primary key,
 name varchar                  |  name varchar                  | name varchar  
);                             | );                             | );

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    SET local search_path to mlwork;
    insert into namedata (id,name) values (7,'name1');
    
    SET local search_path to mmwork;
    insert into namedata (id,name) values (8,'name2');
    
    SET local search_path to mnwork;
    insert into namedata (id,name) values (9,'name3');
END TRANSACTION;
```

Since, the values are to be written to the respective tables, at the end of the transaction, and
at the end of the transaction, the `search_path` is set to `mnwork`, why don't all three values get inserted to the `mnwork.namedata`? How does postgres keep track of multiple `search_paths` being set along the transaction and `commit` based on different `search_path`s?

Comment: The search path is only relevant when you don’t use a schema qualification for your tables and other objects. But you do. I never use a search path, to avoid any confusion

Comment: As @FrankHeikens said, search paths have no effect on qualified identifiers. Search paths are used to determine the order and names of schemas to be searched for unqualified database object identifiers. Another important point, identifiers are resolved when statements are executed, not at commit time; therefore, changing the search path has no effect on any statements executed prior to the path change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the tables in the `INSERT` statements are qualified with the schema name, the current setting of `search_path` has no effect on these statements (except perhaps on any trigger that may be called from the `INSERT` statement).

If you had written `INSERT INTO namedata` each time, the rows would have been inserted in the tables in the same schemas as you explicitly specified.  The setting is in effect in all statements after the `SET LOCAL` that set it, andd it remains in effect until the next `SET LOCAL` or until the transaction ends, whereupon it reverts to the original setting.

Comment: when postgres executes statements inside a transaction and does not commit, does it create/insert(in above case) temporary rows and something like a garbage collector revokes them on a rollback?

Comment: I cannot explain the PostgreSQL architecture in a comment. Read the documentation, for example [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-SPACE-RECOVERY).

Comment: thanks for the link, btw, do you think its possible to write to multiple schemas at the same time? e.g. something like: `set multi search_path to a , b, c; insert into x(y) values(m) ` would insert the row to the table x in all three schemas?

Comment: @juztcode No, that is not possible.